# Where is the blockchain saved, in windows?

Tags: blockchain, windows

I'm kind of mystified. Bitmonerod says it's up to date. I don't see anything in my monero folder that looks like a blockchain. I also searched, using the windows file explorer, for all files bigger than 128MB and didn't find anything. I'm running Windows 10.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

On Windows the blockchain is stored in C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb. It's a hidden folder, but if you simply copy paste aforementioned path into your Windows explorer it will go to it. The folder contains your blockchain (data.mdb).

Comment: Thanks..Windows search is weird. Any way to change where this is being stored?

Comment: Launch bitmonero from the command line with the --data-dir path/to/your/blockchain argument. Thus, if you want to store your blockchain in D:\Monero it would become --data-dir D:\Monero. To reiterate, make sure you launch bitmonerod from the command line. This option won't work if bitmonerod is already launched.

Comment: dEBRYUNE has it right. I came here looking for where it was because when syncing the block chain it tanks my c: drive, which tanks everything else on my computer. So a little tip for anyone else looking for this for the same reason I was, you can move it to another drive by using the mklink command. I put it on a ssd, now I can use my computer again. Thought a little more info might help.

Comment: 2018 sidenote, a more extensive guide to move the blockchain to a custom directory without losing the process: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/how-do-i-move-the-blockchain-data-mdb-to-a-different-directory-during-or-afte/7226#7226

Comment: and where is it saved on macOS?

Comment: @FyodorGlebov `~/.bitmonero` | Note that, by default, this directory is hidden. On Mac OS X, you can typically use `CMD+SHIFT+DOT` to unhide directories.

Comment: Is there a way to change this directory in the app?

Comment: @Sawtaytoes - See: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/how-do-i-move-the-blockchain-data-mdb-to-a-different-directory-during-or-afte/7226#7226

Comment: on linux, is it always in .bitmonero in the home folder?

Comment: Yes, unless another folder was manually specified.