# How do I move the blockchain (data.mdb) to a different directory during (or after) the initial sync without losing the progress?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

I am currently performing the initial sync to the default directory, but my drive is nearly full. How do I move (and subsequently sync) the blockchain to another drive without losing the progress?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is, fortunately, fairly trivial and you won't lose any of the progress. It is done as follows.

**If you're using the GUI, perform the following steps:**

1. Create a new directory on the other/external drive. In addition, create a subdirectory called `lmdb`. Thus, if you, for example, created a directory called `MoneroBlockchain` on the other/external drive, you should also have `MoneroBlockchain/lmdb` (Linux & Mac OS X) or `MoneroBlockchain\lmdb` (Windows)
2. Go to the `Settings` page of the GUI and add the **full path** of the new *directory* as `Blockchain location`
3. Click in another box (on the `Settings` page) to ensure your settings are properly saved.
4. Exit the GUI and make sure to stop the daemon as well.
5. Browse to default directory for the blockchain (`C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` on Windows | `~/.bitmonero/lmdb` on Linux and Mac OS X)
6. Note that aforementioned directories are hidden. On Windows, you can use the explorer to manually browse to it. On Mac OS X, you can typically use `CMD+SHIFT+DOT` to unhide directories. Lastly, on Linux, you can typically use `CTRL + H` to unhide directories.
7. Copy `data.mdb` (the blockchain) to the new *lmdb subdirectory* directory.
8. Restart the GUI.
9. Use `Show status` (on the `Settings`) to verify that your daemon is properly syncing (i.e. fetching new blocks) to the new directory.

---

**If you're using the CLI or running `monerod` separately from the GUI, perform the following steps:**

**[1]** Exit the current `monerod` gracefully by typing `exit`

**[2]** Create a new directory on the other/external drive. In addition, create a subdirectory called `lmdb`. Thus, if you created a directory called `MoneroBlockchain` on the other/external drive, you should also have `MoneroBlockchain/lmdb` (Linux & Mac OS X) or `MoneroBlockchain\lmdb` (Windows).

**[3]** Browse to default directory for the blockchain (`C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` on Windows | `~/.bitmonero/lmdb` on Linux and Mac OS X).

**[4]** Note that aforementioned directories are, by default, hidden. On Windows, you can use the explorer to manually browse to it. On Mac OS X, you can typically use `CMD+SHIFT+DOT` to unhide directories. Lastly, on Linux, you can typically use `CTRL + H` to unhide directories.

**[5]** Copy `data.mdb` (the blockchain) to the new *lmdb subdirectory* directory.

**[6a]** On Windows, open a new command prompt from the same directory as `monerod.exe`. This is done by first making sure your cursor isn't located on any of the files and subsequently doing `SHIFT + right click`. It will give you an option to "Open command window here". If you're using Windows 10, it'll, most likely, give you an option to open the Powershell.

**[6b]** On Linux and Mac OS X, open a new terminal from the same directory as `monerod`

**[7a]** On Windows, type the following command in the command prompt:

`monerod.exe --data-dir path\to\new\directory`

If that doesn't work in the Powershell, type:

`.\monerod.exe --data-dir path\to\new\directory`

If that doesn't work either in the Powershell, type:

`./monerod.exe --data-dir path\to\new\directory`

**[7b]** On Linux and Mac OS X, type the following command in the terminal:

`./monerod --data-dir path/to/new/directory`

**[8]** Note that, if you're running monerod separately, you have to apply the flags every time you start `monerod`. Thus, on Windows, probably most convenient to create a shortcut, go to properties, and add the flags after the `Target`. On Linux and Mac OS X, it's probably most convenient to create a little script.

**[9]** Once `monerod` starts it should state (in the terminal or command prompt) where it's loading the blockchain from. Check whether this is the correct directory.

Comment: Can I check a config file to see if the gui did save the directory at step 3? Because the GUI does show me the correct location and the import raw guide stored everything in the default location.

Comment: For config files, see: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2866/where-are-the-monero-core-configuration-parameters-stored. The blockchain import is done by a different binary, namely `monero-blockchain-import`. I *think* you can add a custom directory there too (using `--data-dir) so it places the imported blockchain (data.mdb) in the custom directory. However, if you already finished importing and it placed the blockchain in the default directory, it's probably best to just use this guide to move the blockchain.

Comment: that does not work... What´s wrong here? Using my Mac with an external Drive... created a new Folder `/Monero/lmdb` copied my existing chain from my local hard drive over - but i'm unable to connect to the daemon. Tried different ways - without any success... --data-dir /Volumes/WD\ 1TB\ Media/Monero/lmdb/data.mdb --data-dir /Volumes/WD\ 1TB\ Media/Monero/lmdb --data-dir /Volumes/WD 1TB Media/Monero/lmdb/data.mdb --data-dir /Volumes/WD 1TB Media/Monero/lmdb Didn't work .... any idea? Thanks in advance...

Comment: A space in the path may cause issues. Perhaps try renaming the external drive to WD1TBMedia and then using `--data-dir /Volumes/WD1TBMedia/Monero`

Comment: As of 2020, there is a Monero Daemon shortcut created on installation, so if you press Cmd and find Monero Daemon, then you right-click it -> Open File Location, then you right-click its shortcut -> Properties, you will see that under Target it has something which is `"F:\Programs\Monero GUI Wallet\monerod.exe" --data-dir F:\ProgramData\bitmonero` for me. You need to manually change the --data-dir to the new directory - since updating the GUI doesn't change this.

Comment: "Go to the Settings page of the GUI and add the full path of the new directory as Blockchain location" ; 

As of 2021 it seems like this does not exist in the macOS GUI

Comment: @user5359531 - Do you still require any assistance?

Comment: Just wanted to add that the top answer worked for me on a 2016 macbook pro running OSX 12.6 (Monterrey). I didn't realize there was a space at end of the name of the external drive which was causing the process not to work. Once I found the space and got rid of it everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **symlink** (`ln -s ...`)to map default directory to a new path (linux cli):

**[1]** move or copy the ~/.bitmonero to new location. I prefer rsync:

**`rsync -avh ~/.bitmonero/ path/to/new/directory/`**

**[2]** Optionally, backup your original ~/.bitmonero:

**`mv ~/.bitmonero ~/bitmonerobak`**

**[3]** Generate a .bitmonero symlink that points to the new directory:

**`ln -s ~/.bitmonero path/to/new/directory`**

monerod's default location (~/.bitmonero) points to your new path and you can run it as normal.

Answer (score -1):

short for linux cli users:

- download & verify from https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases
- tar & cd into monero dir
- create 'monero' dir on your external drive
- run `./monerod --data-dir /path/to/monero`

if all is right the monerod output will tell you