# Changing to new computer - can I avoid having to download the blockchain again?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain

The GUI wallet on my current computer is fully synchronized. I've just bought a new computer and will download the GUI wallet onto it. Can I copy the blockchain from my current computer to the new one, in order to avoid having to download it again? If so, could you please explain the steps?

Comment: You can either place it (data.mdb) in the default directory (`C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` on Windows | `~/.bitmonero/lmdb` on Mac OS X and Linux) or create a new, custom directory and use this guide: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/how-do-i-move-the-blockchain-data-mdb-to-a-different-directory-during-or-afte