# Move blockchain folder on Windows

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, windows, blockchain-import

I have read https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-speed-up-initial-blockchain-sync and downloaded the 27.2 gb raw file.

I had the monero gui installed and specified the directory for the blockchain to: 
`E:\monero`
I have followed all steps from [monero.how](https://monero.how) website but I have a 38.5gb folder in `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` and only 900mb in `E:\Monero`

When I re-launch the Monero gui it still says the directory is on the e-partition, but the sync status says it's almost synced (25 days behind) using the 38.5gb folder.

So it seems that the gui has different settings than the `monero-blockchain-import.exe`? Or what happened? And how can I fix/change it?

Comment: Use that guide ^

Comment: Thank you @Joss Bird for the edit and dEBRUYNE for the guide and approval of the edit. Thanks both :) The thing is that the initial sync was on the E drive and had 900mb in it. I used the import raw guide afterwards and it did not use the setting of the E drive and used the default settings. Perhaps the import.exe needs an adjustment to respect the current settings of the gui client?

Comment: I responded to your other comment here: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/how-do-i-move-the-blockchain-data-mdb-to-a-different-directory-during-or-afte/7226#comment6130_7226