# Monero Daemon shows an error Failed to add TCP Socket

Tags: monerod

Was working ok, then I moved everything to a different HDD and now Deamon refuses to co-operate.
I shut down my AV, Firewall, everything I can think of.
I don't know much about ports, any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Did you properly utilize this guide to move the blockchain? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/how-do-i-move-the-blockchain-data-mdb-to-a-different-directory-during-or-afte