# Change path of blockchain data on Debian?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, linux

I tried to follow the guide here ([How do I move the blockchain (data.mdb) to a different directory during (or after) the initial sync without losing the progress?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/how-do-i-move-the-blockchain-data-mdb-to-a-different-directory-during-or-afte)), but I cannot change the path to my hard drive. The Monero GUI program does not even recognize that I have a hard drive on my computer.

I attached a photo (visible here: https://i.postimg.cc/7ZtQMsmT/ex1.png) and as you can see my hard drive (exthdd) is mounted and recognized by the system but not recognized by the Monero program. Thank you all for all help.

Comment: I've had success in the past just using a symbolic link. Move the file/directory where you want it and just put a symbolic link in ~/.bitmonero point to where you move it to.

Comment: Perhaps you just don't know where the HD has been mounted. If you knew where it was mounted, you'd be able to browse to it in the folder dialog. This is not really a "Monero GUI" issue.