# Store Monero entirely on USB

Tags: new-user

Is there any way to move the blockchain and all logs/folders to a USB stick and keep it there so you don't have files indicating you own Monero stored on your computer?

I've tried moving the blockchain manually but after doing that the daemon cannot connect and it still creates logs in `.bitmonero`.

Debian based.

Comment: With respect to moving the blockchain file, did you look at this guide already? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/how-do-i-move-the-blockchain-data-mdb-to-a-different-directory-during-or-afte

Comment: And for the logs, `--log-file /path/to/log.log`

Comment: anytime I try running the daemon with the blockchain on the usb it gives me the following error
Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.3.0-release)
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Comment: "Couldn't connect to daemon" is a wallet error, not a daemon error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use the options `--data-dir` and `--log-file` appropriately when starting the daemon.