# Monero Wallet's blockchain data refuses to change location

Tags: monerod, windows

I followed [this](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/how-do-i-move-the-blockchain-data-mdb-to-a-different-directory-during-or-afte) guide down to a T, as I'm trying to move the blockchain to `D:\Monero GUI Wallet\bitmonero`. It seemingly worked fine and didn't show any errors, and now I've got the blockchain data in my D-drive.

Once restarted though, the wallet recreates the `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero` directory and begins downloading the entire blockchain there. The GUI's blockchain location still shows `D:\Monero GUI Wallet\bitmonero`, even as I watch the `data.mdb` file download to the C-drive.

This is on Windows 10 and wallet version `0.18.1.2-unknown (Qt 5.15.6)`.

What did I do wrong and how can I force it to use my D-drive?

Comment: Are you starting `monerod.exe` manually?

Comment: I've tried letting it start alone. Also tried cancelling it immediately and then starting monerod.exe (in D-drive) manually. Neither work.

Comment: To be clear, did you start `monerod.exe` manually with the `--data-dir` flag? [This guide](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/how-do-i-move-the-blockchain-data-mdb-to-a-different-directory-during-or-afte) contains instructions for that.